# Scanning a text file into an array and omitting one specified line

Tags: java, arrays, loops, for-loop, filereader

I'm a beginner and need some help. I'm trying to scan a text file into an array line by line, but omitting one line. My text file is

i am

you are

he is

she is

it is

I want to create a method that will scan this and put elements into an array with an exception for one line (that is chosen by entering the String as a parameter for the method). Then erase the original text file and print there the created array (without that one deleted line). Sorry, I suck at explaining.

I have tried this:

```
public static void deleteLine(String name, String line) throws IOException {
    String sc = System.getProperty("user.dir") + new File("").separator;
    FileReader fr = new FileReader(sc + name + ".txt");
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(fr);
    int n = countLines(name); // a well working method returning the number if lines in the file (here 5)
    String[] listArray = new String[n-1]; 
    for (int i = 0; i < n-1; i++) {
        if (scan.hasNextLine() && !scan.nextLine().equals(line))
            listArray[i] = scan.nextLine();
        else if (scan.hasNextLine() && scan.nextLine().equals(line))
            i--;
        else continue;
    }
    PrintWriter print = new PrintWriter(sc + name + ".txt");
    print.write("");
    for (int i = 0; i < n-2; i++) {
        print.write(listArray[i] + "\n");
    }
    print.close()
}
```

I get an error "Line not found" when I enter: deleteLine("all_names","you are") (all_names is the name of the file). I'm sure the problem lies in the for-loop, but I have no idea why this doesn't work. :(

//SOLVED//

This code worked after all. Thanks for answers!

```
public static void deleteLine(String name, String line) throws IOException{
    String sc = System.getProperty("user.dir") + new File("").separator;
    FileReader fr = null;
    fr = new FileReader(sc+name+".txt");
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(fr);
    int n = LineCounter(name);
    String[] listArray = new String[n-1]; 
    for (int i = 0; i < n-1; i++) {
        if (scan.hasNextLine()) {
            String nextLine = scan.nextLine();
            if (!nextLine.equals(line)) {
                listArray[i] = nextLine;
            }
            else i--;
        }
    }
    PrintWriter print = new PrintWriter(sc+name+".txt");
    print.write("");
    for(int i=0;i<n-1;i++){
        print.write(listArray[i]+System.lineSeparator());


    }
    print.close();

}
```

Comment: A note on coding convention: In Java methods start with a lowercase letter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are reading the lines twice scan.nextLine() while comparing and because of that you run out of the lines.

Replace your loop with this one or similar

```
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        if (scan.hasNextLine()) {
            String nextLine = scan.nextLine();
            if (nextLine.equals(line)) {
                listArray[i] = nextLine;
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thank you so much! This exact code did not work, but I worked around it and managed to get what I want.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at how you are comparing String objects. You should use the `equals` method to compare a String's **content**. Using operators like `==` and `!=` compares if the String **objects** are identical.

Now after using `equals` correctly have a look at how you are using `nextLine`. Check its [Javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#nextLine--)

Comment: Thanks, that could also create problems, however the error remains the same even after fixing this. (changed to !scan.nextLine().equals(line) + the same one without exclamation mark line below)

Answer (score 0):

I feel LineCounter(name) works because you did not put a ".txt" there. Try removing the ".txt" extension from the file name in the Filereader and Printwriter objects and see if it works. Usually in windows, the extension is not a part of the file name.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an alternative (easier) solution to do what you want, using easier to understand code. (I think)

Also it avoids multiple 
loops, but uses a single Java 8 stream to filter instead.

```
public static void deleteLine(String name, String line) throws IOException {
    List<String> lines = Files.readAllLines(Paths.get(name));
    lines = lines.stream().filter(v -> !v.equals(line)).collect(Collectors.toList());
    System.out.println(lines);

    // if you want the String[] - but you don't need it
    String[] linesAsStringArr = new String[lines.size()];
    linesAsStringArr = lines.toArray(linesAsStringArr);

    // write the file using our List<String>
    Path out = Paths.get("output.txt"); // or another filename you dynamically create
    Files.write(out, lines, Charset.forName("UTF-8"));
}
```

Comment: Thanks! A little bit too complicated for me right now as I don't really understand all the functions. But this answer will be great for future reference for sure.